# How i can upload stories in telegram account with pyrogram?

Tags: telegram, pyrogram, user-stories

I dont find any method to upload stories in pyrogram or telethon

Can i make method to upload videos or photos on stories ??
Its ok if i dont use pyrogram or telethon and no problem with any other lib

I try to uplode stories to my account on telegram

Answer (score 0):

Current pyrogram version does not support up to date raw functions, you can consider using maintained fork: https://kurimuzon.ru/pyrodocs/telegram/functions/stories/

Comment: Ok i will try it